# How do I set up a page header in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I am running VS2015 with the visual studio crystal report plugin. I have a report in crystal reports and I need to add a text box object into Section 2 (Page Header).  When I click on the black arrow to expand the section and i drag the section down, the section expands but the section is grey with diagonal lines running through the section.  I placed a text box object and entered the text I want to display but when the report is generated, the text in the text box object does not appear on the report.

Does the greying out of the section indicate that the section will not generate? How can I get the text in the text box object to get printed?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Here is a snapshot of what the developer looks like (I apologize for the poor quality as I am developing on a different machine than the one I used to type this question.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That section is suppressed.

To unsuppress it, use the right-click menu from the vertical bar area to the left of the section or go to ***Report, Section Expert...*** and select the target section.